# How to find out whether an Illustrator file or object has been copied from somewhere else

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have received an Illustrator file, as an entry for a competition that I had organised, but I seriously doubt the illustration is completely original and suspect that parts of it are copied from other sources.

I need to be sure of it. How do I find out?

Comment: You could do an inverted image search using google, but you'd probably need to separate the layers, save as file, then upload and check each one. It might be worth it, though, because there could be real consequences.

Comment: The only solution I'm seeing also is a reverse image search. I only use http://tineye.com/ , but there are several others out there: Google "reverse image search" http://bit.ly/1BANfuR

Comment: After using a reverse image search, it's not a bad idea to simply do a normal google search using the keywords related to the image, and look in the image search results. Reverse image search doesn't always work if the colors were changed or some shapes were added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you search the elements that stand out to you as unlikely through Google's reverse image search, that should help.

Obviously you do not want to search for simple elements, but ones that show clear thought and possible originality would be great to use for the reverse search since those are likely to narrowed down as far as possible locations they could originate from.

Comment: Please can you extend your answer? As it stands now all you said was already mentioned in the comments to the question.  Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: @Kurt: Answers posted as comments are free game for being turned into answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try Image Search or Reverse Search. If you know the name of the artist the work is similar to, search for them. If the person who submitted the artwork has an online profile with their art on it, take some time to have a good look at it and read all the comments.

Comment: you're not bringing anything new, this was already mentioned in the comments and in another answer.

Comment: @Luciano: There is some addition to the existing answer. As for the comments, answers posted as comments are free game for being turned into answers.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft no problem with answers content coming from comments, but there's not much extra going on here besides the obvious "if you find the uploader, follow the link"